# drag and drop post multiples files

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I would like to create a form with drag and drop functionality. 
I see filelist is a read-only object and it's and it's not used with drag and drop. So I copy the file into an array and pass it to my form with formdata. But It doesn't work.
Any ideas?

html :

```
<form id="upload" action="action.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<fieldset>
<legend>HTML File Upload</legend>

<input type="hidden" id="MAX_FILE_SIZE" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="300000" />

<div>
    <label for="fileselect">Files to upload:</label>
    <input type="file" id="fileselect" name="fileselect[]" multiple="multiple" />
    <div id="filedrag">or drop files here</div>
</div>


</fieldset>

</form>

<button  id="submitbutton" >Upload Files</button>

<div id="messages">
<p>Status Messages</p>
</div>
```

a reduce of javascript :

```
var myfiles = [];
(function() {

    // getElementById
    function $id(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    }

    // file selection
    function FileSelectHandler(e) {

        // cancel event and hover styling
        FileDragHover(e);

        // fetch FileList object
        var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;

        // process all File objects
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
            myfiles.push(f);
            ParseFile(f);
        }

    }

    $id("submitbutton").onclick = function(){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        formData = new FormData(document.querySelector('form'));
        xhr.open('get','action.php');
        formData.append("files", myfiles);
        xhr.onload = function () {

            console.log(this.responseText);
        };
        xhr.send(formData);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must append files to `FormData` one at a time. The syntax used is similar to what you do in your input element and looks like an array. So append your files like this:

```
myfiles.forEach(file=>{
  formData.append("files[]", file);
});
```

Then, on the server side they will be available in the `files` array.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Do you know if it's possible to call the same page ? For example index.php and the submit form call index.php with news variables in dataform.

Comment: Certainly. The PHP controller, presumably called from `index.php` using your example, would accept, validate and process all the form inputs.

Comment: Ok I will create a new question, I will add new code. But the php code is just var_dump($_POST) or var_dump($_FILES)

Comment: javascript is : `$id("submitbutton").onclick = function(){
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   formData = new FormData(document.querySelector('form'));
   xhr.open('get','index.php');
   myfiles.forEach(file=>{
    formData.append("files[]", file);
   });
   xhr.send(formData);
  }`

Comment: change `$id("submitbutton").onclick = ` to `document.getElementById('submitbutton').onclick = `

Comment: I have a function to do this : `function $id(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
   }`. I post a new question. The problem is because the submit button post just the form without the formdata. Problem is in ajax. I do'nt know if it's possible to call the same page.

Comment: Randy casburn you said it's possible to call same page with Ajax, can you show me ?

Comment: @user3659832 - no, because this is not a coding service. But a quick google found this: https://www.formget.com/how-to-redirect-a-url-php-form/